# I am leaving current PhD position to move to X university. Should I inform X university that I am currently a PhD student?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I am currently a 2nd semester PhD student at **Y** university. My MS is from the same **Y** university and under the same supervisor. In last months of my MS, I told my supervisor that I want to change university after MS. He said that it's okay to look for better PhD positions but we should first finish the project that we have started. (We are working on a project which will be completed in next one or two months)

I was agree with him and decided to stay at **Y** university. Now, I have an interview call from **X** university.

My question is, what should I say when they ask me "Why do you want to leave your current PhD position?"

Comment: What's the honest answer? Why not / why can't you use that?

Comment: _what should I say when they ask me "Why do you want to leave your current PhD position?"_ — You should tell them why you want to leave your current PhD position.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any reason not to just lay it out as you have here. "I think that the program here would better suit my needs and I think I'll get better research and career advice here."

People understand that other people want to change and move "up" when possible.

But I would also take some care that you fulfill your promise to your current advisor about finishing the research to the maximum level possible. You say it is a short-term commitment, so I think it wouldn't be overly burdensome to continue until it is done or until circumstances make it impossible to continue. In case you have to leave it, try to do what you can to leave it in a stable state in which others can, if necessary carry it on. That way your current advisor is more likely to remain a supporter in your future.

But your proposal and your actions seem perfectly normal and natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

I would play it a bit like Buffy said.  In the grand scheme of things you are moving from MS at Y to Ph.D. at X (or X1, X2, etc.).

The fact that you did a little time in Y with advanced course work is not a big deal unless you really WANT to be seen as a transfer student.  But this makes more sense for a year of Ph.D. post bachelors.  Given you are post masters, they know you already have some of the initial direct to Ph.D. coursework done.

So if you can at all truthfully do so, I would just say your plan was always to apply to new schools for Ph.D. but the timing made it work out so you did a little Ph.D. work at the other place.  And I wouldn't even bring it up unless needed.

P.s.  It is extremely normal to move from a terminal masters at one school to a Ph.D. at another.  So it's not like some special explanation is needed.

P.s.s.  There is always some (minor, but some) movement of grad students in Ph.D. programs.  I have seen it among my friends for two reasons:  (1) spouse got job or school in new city, or (2) "trading up" (e.g. Ohio State to Harvard).  I wouldn't want to be seen as a "hopper" (after all they want you to finish at the new school), but some movements are not unheard of.  If you are a "good catch" it should not be a concern, even.